# Hardness of finding all Control Flow Paths of a function

Tags: time-complexity

I have a control flow of function F, I want to know all control flows of this functions.

I.e.,

```
function F {
   A;
   if B {
     B;
   }
   C;
}
```

would have the control flows `{[ABC],[AC]}`. My intuition tells me that the complexity/amount of different control flows is $O(2^m)$ with $m$ being the amount of branches. However, I am unable to find a definitive answer/literature describing the problem and its complexity in detail.

**What is the complexity of calculating all possible control flows trough a function?**

Comment: If you have loops, this amount can easily be infinite. What are the exact restrictions on the function?

Comment: @Dmitry - Yes I have loops however a limited unrolling is ok. I.e., the loop is executed only n times. If it somehow makes the problem (significantly) easier you can assume no loops.